# cannot pickle tensorflow preprocessing layer: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'PreprocessingLayer.make_adapt_function.<locals>.adapt_step'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, normalization

I want to pickle a TensorFlow preprocessing layer, i.e. a normalizer, to later call the mean and variance stored in the normalizer. But after updating to python 3.10 and TF 2.8, the normalizer cannot be pickled anymore. `import dill as pickle` does not work either.
Here is my code:

```
Y_normalizer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
Y_normalizer.adapt(Y_train_raw) 

with open('Y_normalizer.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(Y_normalizer, file)
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'PreprocessingLayer.make_adapt_function..adapt_step'

How can I save the normalizer? And why doesn't it work anymore after updating?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by directly pickling the mean and variance together as a list:

```
Y_normalizer_weights = Y_normalizer.weights
with open('Y_normalizer.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(Y_normalizer_weights, file)

mean = Y_normalizer_weights[0]
variance = Y_normalizer_weights[1]
```